# Multiple plurals per inflectional paradigm slot (Arabic)

Tags: morphology, arabic, nouns, inflection, plurality

Lexemes are generally associated with inflectional paradigms; let us take a nominal for the purpose of this discussion, and more specifically an Arabic nominal. Let's say that we are dealing with a singular masculine (MS) noun which can inflect for number to dual (D) and plural (P).

For instance, take the Arabic noun جُرْح juroH '*wound (injury)*' (using Buckwalter (BW) transliteration for the Roman letters; here's the [mapping](https://camel-tools.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.1/reference/encoding_schemes.html)). For simplicity, let us say that this noun's lexeme has 3 inflectional paradigm slots (MS, MD, and MP). I say for simplicity because I am ignoring cliticization of determiners, prepositions, and pronouns. I include its inflections in the below table. Some notes:

- Its dual is formed by pure concatenative affixation (without stem (denoted by **X**) change).
- Its plural is formed by stem template change (called *broken plural* for Arabic). For some background on templates, all Arabic words can be formed by the process of interleaving a three/four-consonatal root into a pattern which carries a vocalism (the vowels). The word in question in its singular form comes from the triliteral root ج<sup>1</sup>.ر<sup>2</sup>.ح<sup>3</sup>
  (**j**<sup>1</sup>.**r**<sup>2</sup>.**H**<sup>3</sup>), and the singular word is formed by interleaving the root radicals (by digit) into the following pattern: فُعْل (1u2o3). That is, replacing the 1 by **j**, 2 by **r**, and 3 by **H** in the pattern 1u2o3, we get the surface form جُرْح juroH. The plurals of this word are formed in the same fashion for **Y** in the last column of the table, denoting a stem with a pattern different from that of **X**, but formed from the same root.

| MS (X+∅) | MD (X+ayoni) | MP (X → Y) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| جُرْح juroH (juroH+∅) | جُرْحَيْنِ juroHayoni (juroH+ayoni) | جُرُوح (juruwH) **1u2o3** → **1u2uw3** أَجْراح (>ajorAH) **1u2o3** → **>a1o2A3** جِراح (jirAH) **1u2o3** → **1i2A3** |

**Question:**
As you can notice from the table, this word has multiple plurals which mean exactly the same thing, i.e., the paradigm slot for masculine plural (MP) has more than one form. Arabic nominals in general can have one or more broken plurals. In light of this, is there a name for this morphological phenomenon? I see it as kind of the reverse of syncretism, wherein we observe multiple inflectional feature combinations sharing the same form, whereas here, we see multiple forms for the same feature combination (i.e., MP). I searched extensively but could not find anything. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I’m not aware of a technical term for the phenomenon itself, but it’s quite a common thing to have multiple possible variants for the same inflectional form of the same lexeme. English doesn’t really do it with nouns so much (mostly in Classical loans which may or may not naturalise their plurals, e.g., octopus > octopuses, octopodes, octopi), but there are whole groups of verbs that fit the bill: root /CiːC/ > past/pp. /CiːCd/ or /CεCt/ (dream > dreamed/dreamt), root /CɪT/ > past/pp. /CɪTəd/ or /CɪT/ (quit > quitted/quit). Finnish gen.pl. also frequently has at least three variant forms.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes definitely. It's weird that there is no term for it though.

Comment: There may well be – I’ve just not come across it (at least not that I can recall).

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific term either, but I think you'd be understood if you referred to them as 'alternative forms' or 'alternates' or something similar.

Comment: Alright, thank you!